# After upgrading to PHP 7 I started getting "storage folder isn't writable by PHP" errors

Tags: craft-pro, nginx

I just recently upgraded to PHP 7. The browser is now showing following error

```
/home/xxx/craft/storage isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that
```

Have not changed any permissions on any of the folders. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try resetting the permissions of the storage folder:

https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#step-2-set-the-permissions

(It's possible that PHP was running with higher-than-default permissions in the previous setup, in which case everything may have worked even if you hadn't explicitly made the storage folder writable.)